# Creating service on windows xp

Tags: windows-services, windows-xp

I'm creating services on Windows XP.
I have to use a utility that we are using . The utility is making registration in the registry.
My question is that when I'm creating the service a folder name Enum is not created, which I saw was created for all other services.

Is it important ? For what I need it ?

Thanks

Comment: what utility are you using? What does the service do.

Comment: The utility is third party that is locally to this place. 
The service is Client/Server application that connects to other system.

Comment: Where is this "Enum" folder located, i.e. what is the full path to it?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the service APIs (CreateService) to create your service instead of manipulating the registry manually (or via your utility).

The format of the services registry has changed over the years and if you don't use the defined APIs, you may risk malfunctions (you're also going to require a reboot after the registry changes are made because the service controller has now way of knowing about your new service).

Comment: The registry entry format hasn't changed in any incompatible fashion since NT4 days. Adding the registry key as a registry key with an installer does not require a reboot -- you just have to F5 your services applet to get a refresh of the known list displayed to you.  And exactly the same in reverse when uninstalling.  In practice, at work, we have found this more reliable, robust and controllable than using the pre-packaged service install actions.

Comment: As mentined must use API of the third paty

Answer (score 1):

A common windows service doesn't need anything such as "Enum" Directory. It must be something specific in your applications. So if the directory wasn't created automatically, you need to write an installer for your service which creates this directory automatically, or create it manually.

You can use the command "instsrv" if you want to register a new service running under Windows XP.

Cheers
Tomas